# Axios get request not working with auth option

Tags: authentication, vue.js, axios

My Axios request is working fine as long as I'm typing in username and password manually.
But I would like to set the auth option to:

```
    auth: {
      user: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }
```

The moment i define the auth option, i get:

401 (Unauthorized)
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Why is my request not working with auth?

Can I get that running with auth?

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/642 this might help

Comment: use proxy server like Charles to investigate the traffic and see how the request actually looks like.